# main.js in requirejs does not load after a redirect

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, requirejs

I'm using MVC with .NET.

Requirejs loads fine on my application homepage (URL is `http://localhost:62124`) I added a button to redirect users to another page that has a form. The URL after the redirect is `http://localhost:62124/Users/RedirectToSignUp`
I get these error messages in the console

```
http://localhost:62124/Users/Scripts/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Uncaught Error: Script error for "main"
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:5)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:5)
```

Here is my directory structure for the scripts

```
Scripts
|----Custom
|----|---- login.js
|----|---- signup.js
Bootstrap.min.js
jquery-3.3.1.js
jquery.validate.min.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
knockout-3.4.2.js
main.js
modernizer-2.8.3.js
require.js
```

The login page, which is the homepage, loads all the correct scripts. The path for the requirejs is /Scripts/requirejs on this page. However, on the other page, it's trying to find the main.js under `Users/Scripts/main.js` which does not exist.

This is how my main.js looks like

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '/Scripts',
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'jquery-3.3.1.min',
        'jquery.validate': 'jquery.validate.min',
        'jquery.validate.unobtrusive': 'jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min',
        'knockout': 'knockout-3.4.2',
        'login': 'Custom/login',
        'signup': 'Custom/signup'
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery.validate': ['jquery'],
        'jquery.validate.unobtrusive': ['jquery', 'jquery.validate']
    }
});
var base = {}

base.init = function () {

    if (applicationConfig.login) {
        require(['login']);
    }
    if (applicationConfig.signup) {
        require(['signup']);
    }
}

base.init();
```

How can I load the requirejs and main.js correctly, even after the redirect?

**Edit:**

This is how I'm loading the main.js in my _Layout.cshtml

```
<script data-main="Scripts/main" src="~/Scripts/require.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well here is your problem. it tries to pull your js file from http://localhost:62124/Users/Scripts/main.js. And I assume you got it under localhost:62124/scripts/main.js. Sounds like issues with a relative import for the main.js script

Comment: So how your main.js looks like isn't helpful because it can't resolve that file

Comment: Please show us where you import the main.js in your MVC view

Comment: Please update first post with the part where you reference the main,js in your _Layout.cshtml

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by changing

```
<script data-main="Scripts/main" src="~/Scripts/require.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script data-main="/Scripts/main" src="~/Scripts/require.js"></script>
```